# IDE Related, libraries not accessible across IDE platforms

Tags: python, intellij-idea, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Earlier I had installed IDE Intelleji Idea for Python usage, and it worked fine ...

Then I had to install Anaconda and worked in Jupyter Notebook

pip installed new libraries like Seaborn, pandas, numpy, etc

now I see these libs are available in Jupyter but not accessible in IntelliJ Idea

What must I do?

Answer (score 0):

Using jupyter from docker image and pycharm from a binary, each of these run of their own virtual environments. 
The best way I found for proper pycharm libs handling is to run from it's bash console :

```sh
$ python3 -m pip install XXX YYY
```